# How to find out build of all jobs downstream to a certain jobs on jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I know on Jenkins we can view build trends for each job, to see how long each past job took, but is there a way to programatically find that out through Jenkins console?

So if i have a job called parentJob, I want to find all jobs downstream to parentJob and find out how long the most recent build for each of the child jobs took. To make it more interesting I'd like to find the average build time for each recent job and sort it by time descending.